# Is Rum Kosher for Passover?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover, liquor-beer

Specifically, is Bacardi Superior Original Premium Rum kosher for Passover? The label doesn't say so, nor does it say that it's kosher in general for that matter, but since it has a sugar base, wouldn't it be kosher for Passover?

Comment: the tension seems to be betwen the common sense side -- anything manufactured needs to be labeled explicitly K for P and the internet side (the one wiki page on which an unknown respondent said s/he called Bacardi and they said that the product was K for P without a label). The underlying ingredients question would concern some as a slippery slope argument.

Comment: Hello Daniella, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks for your very relevant question! I hope to see you around the site!

Comment: As I point out below, rum is **fermented** sugar cane syrup, which means yeast has been added. Some rums add alcohol as well. Thus it could be chametz and would probably require certification.

Comment: Yeast is a microorganism. Some varieties grow naturally on grain, others would grow naturally on grapes, sugar, or other produce. If you use a grain cultivated yeast, that would be chametz, but you could use a grape yeast which would not be.

Answer (score 3):

Rum, while it can be made *kosher l'Pesach*, needs a certification for Orthodox observance.  Whether it be the contents that could be mixed with it, the facility, or the utensils, it is not KLP by default.

For the Orthodox community (specifically Modern Orthodox), the Orthodox Union puts out a [guide](https://oukosher.org/passover/passover-guide-mobile/) every year that includes items that don't need certification.  Rum is listed as one that does need it.  And, for purposes of rum you already own when cleaning for Passover, it is listed as "Not *Chametz Gamur*" meaning it's not true *chametz* to be cleaned, but should be sold instead.

In 2022, they [list](https://oukosher.org/content/uploads/sites/2/2022/03/Passover_Guide_2022_March9.pdf) three lines that the OU certifies as KLP: Single Cask Nation American Rum, Dead Drop Rum, and [Dead Drop Dark Rum](https://kosherwinedirect.com/products/dead-drop-dark-rum-kosher-for-passover?variant=42533656592602).

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE** Since rum is fermented and has had yeast added (and possibly even alcohol) it would require certification for Passover even if it is kosher without certification for the rest of the year.

---

[CRC](http://www.crcweb.org/LiquorList.pdf) lists rum as kosher unless it is aged in wine casks.

> Unflavored rum is recommended without hashgacha  unless the label
>   indicates that it was aged or finished in  wine casks.

The list shows those that have no hashgacha but are recommended anyway and those that are certified by the OU and AKC. Many of these **require** a hashgacha to ensure that they were not aged in wine casks.

Star k [Rum- Unflavored, including Dark](https://www.star-k.org/resource/list/2COJQJIA/Rum-_Unflavored%2C_including_Dark)

> Certification status: Acceptable WITHOUT Certification

Star k [Rum- Spiced or Flavored](https://www.star-k.org/resource/list/4MLC6KC3/Rum-_Spiced_or_Flavored)

> Certification status: Requires Certification

While sugarcane (from which rum is made) would have no problems, one should double check with a certifier like the OU or Star-K if there are extra ingredients that would affect the Passover status just to make sure. I have sent an email to the OU and star-K to make sure.

According to references that I have found via google, rum is made by adding yeast to sugar cane syrup. Thus, the source of the yeast is critical as it could be chametz.

[How to Make Rum](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Rum)

> Cool the solution to 28 °C (82 °F) and add the hydrated yeast. You may
>   find it helpful to take out about 1 liter of the mash in a jug first;
>   try dissolving the yeast in the smaller jug. Then, when the mixture
>   begins to foam up, incorporate with the rest of the wort

Rabbi Zvi Holland of the star-k answered my email and said

> Requires KFP for a whole variety including possibly added CHOMETZ
>   alcohol in some countries